Wayland walled out of Ubuntu 22.04.4
My home machine:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.5.0-45-generic 
Uptime: 13 mins 
Packages: 3618 (dpkg), 23 (flatpak), 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-purple [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-purple [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M 
Memory: 3121MiB / 15882MiB 

When Ubuntu 22.04 came out originally, I had Wayland as my desktop manager protocol.
But lately - maybe after updating to 22.04.4 - I see that Wayland is not the running protocol. It's just X11.
I tried configuring /etc/gdm3/custom.conf so that Wayland should run, i.e. commenting  out the WaylandEnable=false or else making it WaylandEnable=true
But when I reboot, the Plymouth listing stops around half-way and will not proceed no matter how long (within reason) I wait.
I've heard of Nvidia GPUs having Wayland issues but mine is an AMD - though a bit aged now.
Anyone got any ideas ?
This issue might also tie in to issues I have on updating with certain Wayland env variables, a LibreOffice seize-up and also with a Firefox freezing issue I've had over the last 2 weeks.
